# How to setText to editText of ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView with a Custom Adapter. It shows an image on the left and two lines of text.

mylist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:padding="5dp" />

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#33CC33" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

     </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to set dynamic text to edit text of id "textView1" but this textview will be shown on every row of listview, I only want to change the text on 2nd row.

I have used this code in MainActivity.java

```
package com.chinmay.callblocker;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private TextView extraTxt;

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid, textDescription);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);
    extraTxt = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor e = settings.edit();
    e.putBoolean("switch", false);
    e.commit();

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            /*String selected_item = "List View";
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selected_item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
            if(position == 1) {


                alert.setTitle("Message");
                alert.setMessage("This message will be sent when call blocking is on");

                // Set an EditText view to get user input
                final EditText input = new EditText(getBaseContext());
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        String value = input.getText().toString();
                        extraTxt.setText(value);
                        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // Do something with value!
                    }
                });

                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Canceled.
                    }
                });

                alert.show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView lv ,View view,int position,int imgid) {
    /*String selected_item = "List View";
    Toast.makeText(this, selected_item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

CustomListAdapter.java

```
package com.chinmay.callblocker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by user on 11/4/2014.
 */

public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final Integer[] imgid;
private final String[] textDescription;
AudioManager mAudio;


public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid, String[] textDescription) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;
    this.textDescription = textDescription;


}
public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    final Switch mSwitch = (Switch) rowView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extra_txt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    extra_txt.setText(textDescription[position]);

    mAudio = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    if(position == 0) {

        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor e = settings.edit();

        mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked) {
                    mAudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    e.putBoolean("switch", mSwitch.isChecked());
                    e.commit();
                } else {
                    mAudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                    e.putBoolean("switch", mSwitch.isChecked());
                    e.commit();
                }
            }

        });

    } else if(position != 0) {
        mSwitch.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if(position == 1) {

        }
    }

    return rowView;
};
}
```

Now this code won't work because obviously there is no way to get text view of row 2 and then change it. But I think there must be some way to deal with such problems on ListView.

Comment: your adapter displays data. This data is the model. If you don't modify that data, modifying the view (i.e. the textview displaying your data), that modification will be forgotten as soon as your view is no longer on the screen.

Comment: @njzk2 So what should I do to modify the view?

Comment: The whole model part is missing from your code.

Comment: @njzk2 I have uploaded CustomListAdapter.java

Comment: modifiy `textDescription[position]` and call `notifyDataSetChanged` after that.

Comment: @njzk2 You mean extra_txt[position] and then notifyDataSetChanged(adapter)

Comment: no, I mean `textDescription`. This is in the onItemClick, and `extra_txt` is only mentioned in the adapter. also `extra_txt` is not an array.

Comment: @njzk2 But how can I access textDescription from MainActivity.java

Comment: How should I know? You have `new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid, textDescription);`, but you say nowhere where does `textDescription` come from

Comment: @njzk2 textDescription is in the MainActivity.java, I have replaced it with ... and now I have added `textDescription[1] = value;` and then `notifyDataSetChanged(adapter);` and it's working! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call notifyDataSetChanged() on CustomListAdapter